# Extracting .tar.gz with PHP after rsync

Tags: php, bash, pipeline, tar

I'm trying to extract a .tar.gz that I compress in a pipeline with bash. The pipeline selects files that should be packaged in an update using `rsync` and then compresses them with `tar`:

```
rsync -azp --files-from=${RSYNC_UPDATE_FILE} --ignore-missing-args src update
tar czf ${UFILE} update
```

The files look correct when I open the .tar.gz with a program like WinRar. I then extract the update using PHP in an app.

```
# Get the full path where it should be extracted
$dirpath = $dirpath ?: File::dirname($zippath);

$phar = new \PharData($zippath);

# Check if it's compressed: e.g. tar.gz => tar
$zip = $phar->isCompressed() ? $phar->decompress() : $phar;

try {
    # Extract it to the new dir
    $extracted = $zip->extractTo($dirpath);
} catch (\Exception $e ) {
    throw new CorruptedZip("Unable to open the archive.",424,$e);
}
```

The extracted files have the right permissions, dir structure, etc. but I guess they are still compressed. The files all contain many groups of strings, not PHP code.

```
02a0 048b 2235 bca8 ad5e 4f7e d9be ed1f
5b00 24d5 9248 8994 2c75 f778 e293 74db
6401 a802 0af5 55e1 52fc fb37 80ff f99f
```

Can anyone see where I'm missing a step?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No errors. Everything extracts and then unpacks into the right places, but the files are ... wrong? Compressed? It's series of blocks of 4 char strings

Comment: Don't the `.gz` files end up extracting down into `.tar` files which then must also be extracted (unzipped)? What happens if you try to unzip one of those files?

Comment: I'll check it out. `PharData::decompressFiles`? Still re-downloading all the untracked dependencies that the bad update messed up...

Comment: @Dave, I tried a .zip, .tar and .tar.gz extension on an individual file and winrar is yelling that it is an "unknown format or damaged".

Comment: Calling `PharData::decompressFiles` errors out. I can't catch the exception. Working on it.

Comment: It's strange, the contents of the file resembles the output that you would see in some hex editors: https://www.romhacking.net/utilities/screenshots/574screenshot1.jpg Is it possible that the output of a class is getting dumped into the files prematurely? Seems like a non-breaking failure in PharData.

Comment: Almost like PharData is making a failed attempt to use an underlying system utility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The error was due to an unmentioned process. The `UploadedFile` class in Laravel was interpreting the mimetype of the file as `application/x-gzip`, with an empty extension, so the resulting file was saved as `[hashed_file_name].` instead of `[hashed_file_name].tar.gz`. Then (on another server) I was using `GuzzleHttp` to get the file, and `Symfony` to guess the extension.

```
$extension = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance()->guess($contentType);
```

Because of the mimetype, the rebuilt file, using `Content-Type` header to get the extension, was simply `.gz` instead of `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`. Changes to my upload script fixed it.

```
$alias = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$mimetype = $file->getMimeType();
$extension = $file->guessClientExtension() ?: pathinfo($alias, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ( ends_with($mimetype, 'x-gzip') && ends_with($alias, ['tar.gz', 'tgz']) ) {
    $mimetype = 'application/tar+gzip';
    $extension = 'tar.gz';
}

$hash = $file->hashName();
if ( ends_with($hash, '.') ) {
    $hash .= $extension;
}

$path = $file->storeAs($storage, $hash);
```